# Split string containing Chinese or Japanese or English into words

Tags: java, parsing, unicode

How can I split a string containing Chinese or Japanese or English into words by using regex or any utility class?

Example 1:

> 根據從2013年的一項研究，由一群來自美國俄亥俄州立大學的研

Output 1:

> 根 據 從 2013 年的 一 項研究，由 一 群來 自 美 國 俄 亥 俄 州 立 大 學 的 研

Example 2:

> According to a 2013 study by a research group from the US to

Output 2:

> According, to, a, 2013, study, by, a, research, group, from, the, US, to

It's certain that the input string will not mix English with Japanese - both will come in separate strings; but yes, an English string should also be split by this piece of code:

```
words = input.split("[ ./()\\[\\]=,<>;\"']+");
```

If this is not possible in Java, please suggest if the Non-English input strings could be separated by whitespace characters only.

Comment: May I ask why there is no space in-between "年的", "項研究" and "群來" in output 1?

Comment: Sorry, no idea about Chinese, so by mistaken it got happened.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem that you may have with Chinese (and maybe Japanese as well, but I don't know as much about it) is that the word breaks are contextual.  Sometimes two characters will be two separate words, sometimes the same two characters will be a single word.

So I think you will need to parse the text to be able to do this.

Comment: definitely with Japanese it's contextual, no regex will begin to do this. for the most part there is no white space, knowing where words begin and end depends on things like recognizing kanji, knowing how verbs and adjectives are conjugated, and recognizing particle characters. you'd need a natural language parser.

Comment: Well, I suppose I could edit it to say "You can't" – not all questions can be answered within the bounds that the asker hoped for. It's a reasonable enough question, but the answer isn't "like this…" it's "you can't because…"

Comment: @dlu, Yes I tried a natural language parser "java.text.BreakIterator", and it works fine on Japanese language but not full fill the English splitting by "[ ./()\\[\\]=,<>;\"']+"
. So I was looking for a Regex to just include the UNICODE space for non-English languages.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1:

> 根據從2013年的一項研究，由一群來自美國俄亥俄州立大學的研

Output 1:

> 根 據 從 2013 年的 一 項研究，由 一 群來 自 美 國 俄 亥 俄 州 立 大 學 的 研

This is incorrect Chinese.
The correct output should be:

> 根據 從 2013 年 的 一項 研究，由 一群 來自 美國 俄亥俄州 立 大學 的 研

You need a library for Chinese words to do this.

Comment: Ok...Tell my any free library for Java??